# Copy elements from shp to GDB layer

Tags: shapefile, pyqgis, esri-geodatabase

I am trying to copy elements from a shp to a GDB.

I took inspiration from [this link](http://www.purplelinux.co.nz/?p=138), but after execution, my elements do not appear in the database. However, when I look in the table, it says 9 elements are present, but there are no lines in the table.

Also, the OGR log window displays the following error :

> Data source is invalid (Cannot open geodatabase at the moment since it is in 'FID hack mode')

I am new to pyQgis so I'm open to any suggestion about the pseudo code below.

```
##Conversion to GDB=name
##src1=vector
##src2=vector
##src3=vector


from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import iface
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from time import *
import os
import processing
from datetime import datetime
from PyQt4.QtGui import QDockWidget
import subprocess
import glob
import shutil, errno

#*********************************************************************************************************************************************
#Initialisations
src_layers=[src1, src2, src3]
i=0



print "START____ " + strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime())


#Groups for output layers
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
displayGroup = root.insertGroup(0, "GDB_"+str(tm))


#*********************************************************************************************************************************************
#1.Opening

layerlink= #string to open GDB in Qgis(removed from pseudocode), similar path/to/gdb/folder.gdb|layer=dest
GDB_layer = QgsVectorLayer(layerlink, GDB_str, "ogr")


GDB_layer.startEditing()
for srcL in src_layers[i]:
    #Open the source layers
    src_layer= QgsVectorLayer(srcL, srcL, 'ogr')  

#*********************************************************************************************************************************************
#2. add source layer fields to the GDB 
    src_layer_attrib_names = src_layer.dataProvider().fields()
    src_attributeList = src_layer.dataProvider().fields().toList()
    newattributeList=[]
    for attrib in src_attributeList:
        if GDB_layer.fieldNameIndex(attrib.name())==-1:
            newattributeList.append(QgsField(attrib.name(),attrib.type()))
    GDB_layer.dataProvider().addAttributes(newattributeList)
    GDB_layer.updateFields()


#*********************************************************************************************************************************************
#3. Copy source elements to the GDB

#Copy features over to the the new memory layer
    GDB_layer_attribute_list=GDB_layer.dataProvider().fields().toList()
    cfeatures=[]
    xfeatures = src_layer.getFeatures()
    for xfeature in xfeatures:
        #Create destination feature
        cfeature = QgsFeature()
        #Populate feature with geometry
        xgeometry = xfeature.geometry()
        cfeature.setGeometry(xgeometry)
        #Populate feature with attributes
        cfeature_Attributes=[]
        for GDB_QGSfield in GDB_layer_attribute_list:
            attribute_field=GDB_QGSfield.name()
            #Get old attribute value and append
            idx = src_layer.fieldNameIndex(attribute_field)
            if idx>=0:
                cfeature_Attributes.append(xfeature.attributes()[idx])
        cfeature.setAttributes(cfeature_Attributes)
        cfeatures.append(cfeature)
    GDB_layer.dataProvider().addFeatures(cfeatures)
    GDB_layer.commitChanges()
    GDB_layer.updateExtents()
    print "nb : " + str(GDB_layer.featureCount())
    #here the count should increase but the number of features stays 9

#6. Add layers to display in Qgis 

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(GDB_layer, False)
displayGroup.addLayer(GDB_layer)

print "OK_______ " + strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime())
```